# References are missing again after Build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added reference and its OK but after build its show like this again
guys help me to fix this things. I really don't know what is happening!!!. my target framework is 4.5.

[image]

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Web API do you have installed via NuGet?

Comment: I've install 4.0 version sir

Comment: Try restore nuget packages